# Excluding cases from Map

Tags: list-manipulation, map

I'm doing operations of the form:

```
PowerMod[#, -1, 126]+# & /@ Range[1, 125]
```

When a number is not invertible, I don't want it to be included in the result set. I do that with

```
Complement[Quiet[Check[PowerMod[#,-1,126]+#, ∅], PowerMod::ninv]& /@ Range[1, 125], {∅}] 
(* {2, 34, 92, 106, 110, 124, 128, 142, 146, 160, 218, 250} *)
```

However, I'm not completely happy with this since I'm including things in the result set that I know I'm going to remove. Is there a way to this without doing that?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I would use the following,

```
Quiet[
  Check[
   PowerMod[#, -1, 126] + #,
   ##&[],
   PowerMod::ninv
  ]& /@ Range[125],
  PowerMod::ninv
]
(*
{2, 106, 34, 110, 106, 92, 34, 146, 142, 92, 146, 124, 128, 106, 160, 
110, 106, 92, 160, 146, 142, 92, 146, 124, 128, 106, 160, 110, 106, 
218, 160, 146, 142, 218, 146, 250}
*)
```

where `##&[]` inserts a `Sequence[]` into the list when `Check` encounters a message.

Also, since `Quiet[Check[..., msgs], msgs]` is such a common idiom, I would encapsulate it into a separate function,

```
ClearAll[quietCheck];
SetAttributes[quietCheck, HoldAll];
quietCheck[e_, f_] := Quiet[Check[e, f]]
quietCheck[e_, f_, m_] := Quiet[Check[e, f, m], m]
```

which simplifies things quite a bit

```
quietCheck[PowerMod[#, -1, 126] + #, ## &[], PowerMod::ninv] & /@ Range[125]
(*
{2, 106, 34, 110, 106, 92, 34, 146, 142, 92, 146, 124, 128, 106, 160, 
110, 106, 92, 160, 146, 142, 92, 146, 124, 128, 106, 160, 110, 106, 
218, 160, 146, 142, 218, 146, 250}
*)
```

To clean up the duplicates, normally I would use `DeleteDuplicates`, but it is likely that you want the result in sorted order. So, `Union` is a better bet,

```
Union@%
(*{2, 34, 92, 106, 110, 124, 128, 142, 146, 160, 218, 250}*)
```

---

Lastly, if you are interested in what input maps to each output, you need to do a bit more work. In v10, this requires only a little more work,

```
GroupBy[Last -> First] @ Map[
 quietCheck[{#, PowerMod[#, -1, 126] + #}, ## &[], PowerMod::ninv]&] @ Range[125]
(*
<|2 -> {1}, 106 -> {5, 17, 47, 59, 89, 101}, 34 -> {11, 23}, 
 110 -> {13, 55, 97}, 92 -> {19, 31, 61, 73}, 
 146 -> {25, 37, 67, 79, 109, 121}, 142 -> {29, 71, 113}, 
 124 -> {41, 83}, 128 -> {43, 85}, 160 -> {53, 65, 95, 107}, 
 218 -> {103, 115}, 250 -> {125}|>
*)
```

where I take advantage of the operator forms of `GroupBy` and `Map`. The argument `Map` now returns the ordered pairs, `{input, output}`, and `GroupBy` organizes them by `output -> {inputs ...}`.

Comment: Very nice. Thank you.

Comment: @mhp I added a note about duplicates, as it seems you want them removed, too.